# SSD's SMART Status not supported behind DELL PERC H730 Mini controller

Tags: centos, temperature, sata, smart

I would like to output the temperature for each of my drives (NVME, SATA, SAS) in my Dell R630, but it couldn't show my SATA **Samsung SSD 870 EVO 250GB** (`/dev/sdc`)'s temperature, which is behind DELL PERC H730 Mini controller:

`hddtemp` command shows:

```
/dev/sda: SAMSUNG AREA7680S5xnNTRI: 37°C
/dev/sdb: SAMSUNG AREA7680S5xnNTRI: 36°C
/dev/sdc: DELL PERC H730 Mini: S.M.A.R.T. not available
```

When I tried to use `smartctl`, it shows:

```
Smartctl open device: /dev/sdc failed: DELL or MegaRaid controller, please try adding '-d megaraid,N'
```

I then use   `smartctl -a -d megaraid,0 /dev/sdc`

It does shows my device name correctly:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 870 EVO 250GB
```

and

```
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

but SMART status shows:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Status not supported: ATA return descriptor not supported by controller firmware
```

May I know how to find out the temperature of the SSD behind DELL PERC H730 Mini controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ATA return descriptor not supported by controller firmware
```

If I understand this correctly, it means the controller did not understand the SMART response given by the disk, and so is not able to pass the information to `smartctl`.

If there are firmware updates available for your controller, one of them might add the necessary support.

Answer (score 0):

For SATA/IDE HDD drives the only way to get the drive temperature is via the SMART interface. Since your controller seemingly doesn't properly support SMART commands, there's no way.

I'd also recommend trying the latest version of SMARTmontools (which is 7.3) because there have been related changes to the MEGAraid controller code.